# Why won't the POSIX function open() accept my path* variable

Tags: linux, posix

```
   int fd=-1;
   char *filename = "/home/user/POSIXfunctions/testfiles/testfile.txt";
   //Arbitary size for the buffer?? How to optimise.
   //Dynamic allocation is a choice but what is the
   //right way to relate the file size to bufffer size.

   fd=open(filename , O_WRONLY , mode);
   if(-1 == fd)
   {
      perror("Open Failed");
      return 1;
   }
```

I borrowed this code from another user in attempt to understand posix functions but when i ask it to open my filename which i specified on top it gives me this error.

```
Open Failed: No such file or directory
```

Why does it do this? The path is correct, not misspelled or anything. Anyone know what the problem is? I'd like to be able to give it specifications all the way from root.

EDIT: Took out some of the unnecessary variables

Comment: Check if you have write permissions to the file.

Comment: after ls -ll: -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    10 Sep 16 10:25 testfile.txt, So yes i think i do.

Comment: @user2824512 you should run `ls -l /home/user/POSIXfunctions/testfiles/testfile.txt`

Comment: Also why do you sepcify the mode? I think open is defined with S_I* modse only if you use O_CREAT flag.

Comment: There were a few open(), most of them i saw them with a bunch of modes so since i didnt want to truncate or create the file, i just left O_WRONLY. I'll try without. As for running ls -l path, i did and got `-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 10 Sep 16 10:25 /home/user/POSIXfunctions/testfiles/testfile.txt`

Comment: Try: fd=open(filename, O_WRONLY);
Also please run "echo $USER" and "groups"

Comment: Same error with `fd =open(filename, O_WRONLY);`. After running "echo $USER" i get only my account name "user" (not really 'user', but that's how i put it before so 'user' rather than what it is). if i do `echo $user` it comes out blank. If i do `echo $GROUP` it comes out blank as well.

Comment: Try to run "touch /home/user/POSIXfunctions/testfiles/testfile.txt"

Comment: Tried that, nothing happened. I deleted testfile.txt afterwards and ran touch again, and it created the file as an empty file. Tried running my program again and nothing, got the same error: `Open Failed: No such file or directory`. Would this have anything to do with my libraries or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and ran it on my Linux box and it works. So my guess is that this file doesn't really exist. 
Check again if this file exists (you said that you omitted the actual user from the path for instance) 
Regarding your question of libraries - it has nothing to do with libraries.

Comment: First of all, thank you for all the help so far.  No no, i mean that i changed my username to 'user' for the sake of this question, i did copy it using that same format, i just changed the names a bit for the question. Do you think it could have anything to use with outdated versions of anything? I'm running this on ubuntu 14.04 if that's any information.

Comment: It has nothing to do with libaries or versions. The file doesn't exist. Copy the EXACT filename from the C file and run ls on it. Probably you will get "No such file or directory".

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following reasons why your program is not working:

1) File does not exist. As suggested above run ls -al with absolute path given in youn C program should tell you if the file exists

2) You don't have permission to write to the file. Run chmod 666 /path/to/file and try running your program. Other way of checking if permission is an issue is to use sudo to run the program.